# In Photoshop how do I create a heat wave/shimmer/etc effect?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

As the title says, what is the best way in Photoshop to create a heat wave/shimmer/etc effect? Ideally I would like it be sequenced somehow, so I can output this to a series of frames - but if not, so be it.

If you're not sure what I mean by heat shimmer
http://flash-effects.com/tutorial-heat-haze-effect/

Thanks

Comment: i dont see why it was downvoted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this tutorials if this can help :

- [Heat Wave effect](http://www.webdesign.org/photoshop/special-effects/heat-wave.10335.html)

---

Plugin :

[Heat Haze Flash Filter](http://www.flash-filter-net-heat-haze-effect.com-about.com/)

hope they will lead you to your  output....

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way, maybe with programming and plugins, but to make this effect only with Photoshop as is you will need to use **Smudge tool**. I do it all the time. Use images for reference. And dont be too hard in strength of smudge tool.